# Multi-leveled multi-site on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, native, hierarchy

is there an opportunity to make multi-leveled (by hierarchy) multi-site support within drupal's native multi-site solution? 
Here's the example:

```
    --example.com
    ----yyy.example.com (blocks&content shared between it's parent and the same level     domains)
    ------xxx.yyy.example.com (blocks&content shared between it's parent and the same level     domains)
    ----zzz.example.com
    ----aaa.example.com
    ------bbb.aaa.example.com and so on...
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do each multi site one-by-one, and you have to set different database prefixes for each multi-site (you can change that in sites/{multisite_name}/settings.php). So build your multi-sites like this:

1) Build example.com

2) Build example.com/yyy multi-site site. (with prefix 'prefix_xxx_')

3) Build example.com/xxxyyy multi site site. (with prefix 'prefix_xxxyyy_')

and so on...

After ask your web hosting service admin to redirect:

1) example.com/yyy to yyy.example.com

2) example.com/xxxyyy to xxx.yyy.example.com

and so on...

The shared database tables you should specify manually one-by-one at the sites/{multisite_name}/settings.php file like this:

```
$db_prefix = array(
    'default'   => 'prefix_xxx_',
    'users'     => 'prefix_xxxyyy_',
    'sessions'  => 'prefix_xxxyyy_',
    'role'      => 'prefix_xxxyyy_',
    'authmap'   => 'prefix_xxxyyy_',
    'sequences' => 'prefix_xxxyyy_',
);
```